# get value of atribute of class stored on NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c

I'm translating a C code to understand objective-C differences from C.
I want to translate this instruction.

```
new_fitness += abs(int(population[i].str[j] - target[j]));
```

`new_fitnees` is an integer var. `Target` is an string and population is a  which contains an string atribute called `str`.

I tried with this secuence:

```
new_fitness += abs( [[population objectAtIndex:i] cadena characterAtIndex:j] - [target characterAtIndex:j] );
```

I obtain an error message that tells a : is missing in first `characterAtIndex`.

`new_fitnees` is an NSInteger var. `Target` is an NSString and population is an *NSMutableArray* which contains an string atribute called `cadena`.

Finally, It's better in Objetive-C split the C operation into 3 or 4 small operations? I think the sequence I did obtain i Obj-C is too complex to read.

Comment: It's much easier to understand the code if you break it down into small operations, particularly if you're having trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wtf is "cadena" remove it. Also you will need intValue for objects

```
NSInteger new_fitness = 0;
NSString *target = @"test";
NSMutableArray *population = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"cadena"];

new_fitness += abs( [[population objectAtIndex:0] characterAtIndex:1] -[target characterAtIndex:1]);
```

just tested - see no error

Comment: yeah I know i need to use intValue. But i don't know where to put this method to use with the atribute cadena (string)